# How can I use an object pool for optimization in AndEngine?

Tags: android, java, andengine

I have read up on a tutorial that allows you to reuse sprites that are re-added to the scene such as bullets from a gun or any other objects using an ObjectPool.

In my game i have a variation of sprites about 6 all together with different textures.

This is how the object pool is set up with its own class extending Java's GenericPool class

```
public class BulletPool extends GenericPool<BulletSprite> {
private TextureRegion mTextureRegion;

 public BulletPool(TextureRegion pTextureRegion) {
  if (pTextureRegion == null) {
 // Need to be able to create a Sprite so the Pool needs to have a TextureRegion
 throw new IllegalArgumentException("The texture region must not be NULL");
 }
 mTextureRegion = pTextureRegion;
} 

/**
* Called when a Bullet is required but there isn't one in the pool
*/
@Override
protected BulletSprite onAllocatePoolItem() {
return new BulletSprite(mTextureRegion);
 }

/**
 * Called when a Bullet is sent to the pool
*/
@Override
protected void onHandleRecycleItem(final BulletSprite pBullet) {
pBullet.setIgnoreUpdate(true);
pBullet.setVisible(false);
}

  /**
  * Called just before a Bullet is returned to the caller, this is where you write  your initialize code
* i.e. set location, rotation, etc.
 */
   @Override
 protected void onHandleObtainItem(final BulletSprite pBullet) {
  pBullet.reset();
}
}
```

As you see here it takes a TextureRegion parameter. The only problem i am facing with this is that i need to have 6 different sprites recycled and reused in the ObjectPool. This ObjectPool is set up to only use one TextureRegion.

Any idea's or suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

In AndEngine you need to `textureRegion.clone()` or `textureRegion.deepCopy()` depending on the version of AndEngine that you use.

This will make sure that each sprite uses independent graphics. Symptom if you don't is that all sprites will have same tile index for example or same modifiers applied.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but let's see.

I have never used AndEngine, but if you create a texture atlas with all your shot sprites, the single TextureRegion can determine which sprite to use for each.

A sprite atlas is a big texture which contains several inside it, usually tiled in a regular fashion. You can specify which one to paint each time by using different regions of the texture. For some more info, check this Gamasutra article: http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/2530/practical_texture_atlases.php

Answer (score 0):

Oh I just know what you want. I applied it to my game with the help of one of the stackoverflow answer.

If you are having to use 4 textures. you can iterate with a int variable, and use it like this.

you see onallocatePoolItem

```
@Override
protected Bubble onAllocatePoolItem() {
    switch(textureOrder){
        case 0:
            return new Bubble(0, 0, aITiledTextureRegionA,ResourcesManager.getInstance().vbom);
        case 1:
            return new Bubble(0, 0, aITiledTextureRegionB,ResourcesManager.getInstance().vbom);
        case 2:
            return new Bubble(0, 0, aITiledTextureRegionC,ResourcesManager.getInstance().vbom);
        default:
            //this is in case you specified something unknown, you can log an error or something
            return new Bubble(0, 0, aITiledTextureRegionA,ResourcesManager.getInstance().vbom);
    }
}
```

and when calling it.

```
public Bubble obtainPoolItem(int textureOrder){
this.textureOrder = textureOrder;
return this.obtainPoolItem();
}
```

You can also refer the answer in stack overflow which helped me.
[Multiple textures in objectpool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25303731/2026280)